# Java matcher group capturing

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

EDIT: I'd also need, if possible, to have the regex match the string format

```
[id='value1' or id='value2' or ... or id='valueN']
```

and also capture all the values.

I have a piece of code that doesn't work as I'd expect and I'm not sure where's my mistake.
Basically I have a string like

```
[id='id1' or id='id2' or id='id3']
```

and I need to find all the values such as `id1`, `id2`, and `id3`.

```
final String regex = "\\[id='([^']+)'(?:\\s*or\\s*id='([^']+)')*\\]";
final String text = "[id='id1' or id='id2' or id='id3']";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

If I do

```
while(matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

I only get

```
id1
```

With

```
if (matcher.matches())
{
   System.out.println("Groups count: " + matcher.groupCount());
   for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)
   {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
   }
}
```

I get

```
id1
id3
```

Expected output would be

```
id1
id2
id3
```

Neither output is the expected one. Could someone please point me if the regex is wrong or is it because of the group finding part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a  regex to match all the id values.

```
String s = "[id='id1' or id='id2' or id='id3']";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=id=')[^']+");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the response. It works as you mention, but the regex is not restrictive enough to match the pattern. Other strings such as "[id='id1' and id='id2' and id='id3']" would match the regex. Is there a way to have both the validation and the capture having only one regex? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
id='([^']*)'
```

This should do it with a `g` flag.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/12

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc of `Matcher#find()` states

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

If the pattern contained multiple captured groups, you'll be able to retrieve them all in the same `find()` iteration.

So you could just do this

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Groups count: " + matcher.groupCount());
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

which will give you the same result as your attempt with `Matcher#matches()`.

Now, why is `id2` missing from the results?

That's because groups within a quantified expression only report the last capture.

The other answers provide solutions.